# Matrix of a Linear Operator (Change of Basis)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

Let $X$ be the vector space of polynomials $p(x)$ having real coefficients and degree at most 2. Consider the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{x^2-x,1,x^2+x\}$ of $X$. The differentiation operator $D: X \to X$ given by $Dp(x) = p'(x)$ is linear. What is the matrix of $D$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$?

It's been a while, so I'm just writing this to ask for a check. First, I will calculate the image of each basis vector under the transformation. We have,

\begin{align*}
D(x^2-x) &= 2x-1\\
D(1) &= 0\\
D(x^2+x) &= 2x+1.
\end{align*}

To find $\lbrack D \rbrack_{\mathcal{B}}$, I need to find the coordinate vector of the image of each of these basis vectors. We can find these by solving the linear systems,
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix} &\sim \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0 &-1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}
This results in the vectors $(-1 \ \ -1 \ \ 1)$, $(0 \ \ 0 \ \ 0)$, and $(-1 \ \ 1 \ \ 1)$, so the matrix is,

\begin{align*}
\lbrack D \rbrack_{\mathcal{B}} =\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: What is the basis? $\mathcal{B} = \{x^2-x,1,x^2+2\}$ or $\mathcal{B} = \{x^2-x,1,x^2+x\}$?

Comment: Sorry it should have been $x^2+x$. I corrected it in the edit.

Comment: Write $u=x^2+x, v=1, w=x^2-x$. This means $D(u)=u-w-v$ which should be shown in the matrix. Use this idea to check the other results as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is correct. Note that
\begin{align}
&D(x^2-x)=(-1)(x^2-x)+(-1)(1)+1(x^2+x);\\
&D(1)=0(x^2-x)+0(1)+0(x^2+x);\\
&D(x^2+x)=(-1)(x^2-x)+1(1)+1(x^2+x).
\end{align}
Therefore, the matrix of $D$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}=\{x^2-x,1,x^2+x\}$ is given by
$$[D]_\mathcal{B}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the check. Your way is much more quick and elegant!